# An alternative proof of Bayesian Cramer-Rao

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, estimation-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

My question is:

> Are there an alternative proof of Cramer-Rao lower bound that does not use
> Cauchy-Swartz inequality?

Let me outline the classical proof and explain why I am interested in this question.

Choose some function $g(X,Y)$. Then,
\begin{align}
E[ (X-E[X\mid Y]) g(X,Y)] \le   \left|   E[ (X-E[X\mid Y]) g(X,Y)]  \right|  \le \sqrt{ E \left[ (X-E[X\mid Y])^2 \right] E[g(X,Y)^2] }.
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
E \left[ (X-E[X\mid Y])^2 \right]  \ge  \frac{\left|   E[ (X-E[X\mid Y]) g(X,Y)]  \right|}{E[g(X,Y)^2]}.
\end{align}

The proof is completed by choosing $g(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} \log (f_{XY}(x,y) ) $ and noting that then  $ E[ (X-E[X\mid Y]) g(X,Y)]=-1$. This gives us the Cramer-Rao lower bound
\begin{align}
E \left[ (X-E[X\mid Y])^2 \right]  \ge \frac{1}{E \left[ \left(\frac{d}{dx} \log (f_{XY}(X,Y) )  \right)^2 \right]}.
\end{align}

The choice of $g(X,Y)=\frac{d}{dx} \log (f_{XY}(x,y) ) $ always seemed mysterious to me (but this is not the main reason for ask this question). That is why I am wondering whether there is a more "natural" proof where the quantity  $\frac{d}{dx} \log (f_{XY}(x,y) )$ appearance is more obvious.

For example, it would be nice if we can derive an inequality by showing that

\begin{align}
E \left[ (X-E[X\mid Y])^2 \right]  = \frac{1}{E \left[ \left(\frac{d}{dx} \log (f_{XY}(X,Y) )  \right)^2 \right]}+c,
\end{align}
where $c$ is non-negative.

Comment: It is possible to write this proof a bit differently in a way you find more natural. But the key step uses convexity, so there is no way to avoid Cauchy-Schwarz or an equivalent inequality.

Comment: @DeaneYang I don't see how convexity comes in. Could you show this proof?  Another question. Why do you think there is no proof that avoids Cauchy-Schwartz but uses some other inequality?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is equivalent to saying that the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is convex. Any proof of the Cramer-Rao inequality has to use a convexity inequality like that, and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is the simplest possible one, since $x\mapsto x^2$ is the simplest convex function.

Comment: @DeaneYang So, how about Jensen's inequality, can we use it to show Cramer-Rao inequality?

Comment: Yes. It's a more general inequality. Cauchy-Schwartz is a special case of Jensen.

Comment: @DeaneYang Sure. But do you think Jensen's inequality is sufficient to show CR bound?

Comment: If it implies Cauchy-Schwarz, it has to be sufficient.

Comment: In the step where you use Cauchy-Schwarz, just use Jensen instead.

Comment: @DeaneYang But how would you do that with a product of two terms. How would you separate the terms?  Can you post this?

Comment: Sorry but that's not a research level question. You should try to figure it out yourself. It might take a while. It always does the first few times.

Comment: @DeaneYang The question is about an alternative proof of CR bound. It didn't get flagged for being irrelevant for this site.   Now, you are saying it can be done with Jensen's instead of Cauchy-Swartz.  To me, this seems like you have an alternative proof.  I don't see why you would not post it, but it is up to you.

Comment: What I meant to say is that proving that Jensen implies Cauchy-Schwarz is not a research level question.

Answer (score 4):

In line with Deane's comment, this is an "answer" that also uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but does so in a way that you might find more natural.  I'll use different notation than yours (sorry; pushed for time and I'll probably mess it up if I attempt to translate quickly).

Take a family of probability density functions $f(-; \theta)$ parametrized by some real $\theta$, and an unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$. The Cramér-Rao bound is a lower bound on $\text{Var}(\hat{\theta})$.  Your implicit challenge is to derive it in a way that seems more natural than the proof you give.

Let's begin by writing down the definition of $\hat{\theta}$ being an unbiased estimator:
$$
\theta = \int \hat{\theta}(x) f(x; \theta) \, dx
$$
for all $\theta$.  Because this holds for all $\theta$, we can differentiate both sides with respect to $\theta$, and I hope you'd agree that this is a fairly natural step.  The result is
$$
1 = \int \hat{\theta}(x) \text{sc}(x; \theta) f(x; \theta) \, dx
$$
where $\text{sc} = \frac{\partial f/\partial\theta}{f}$ (called the **score**).  Now the right-hand side is a covariance:
$$
1 = \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta}, \text{sc}).
$$
I hope you'd agree that it's natural to use the fact that correlation coefficients always have absolute value $\leq 1$. (That's basically the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.)  This gives
$$
1 \leq \sqrt{\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \text{Var}(\text{sc})}.
$$
And rearranging, that's exactly the Cram\'er-Rao bound:
$$
\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \geq 1/\text{Var}(\text{sc}).
$$
(The variance of the score is called the **Fisher information**.)

Comment: This is the parametric case, right? I am looking at Bayesian. Does your proof still hold?

Comment: You should just try adapting the parameteric proof to the Bayesian case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the following re-arrangement of the argument will help remove the mystery of the choice of $g(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln f(x,y)=\frac{f'_x(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$, where $f:=f_{X,Y}$ and ${}'_x$ denotes the partial derivative in $x$.

Assume appropriate regularity conditions, whatever are needed for the manipulations below. Integrating by parts, we have
\begin{equation}
 \int x f'_x(x,y)\,dx=-\int f(x,y)\,dx, 
\end{equation}
whence 
\begin{equation}
EXg(X,Y)=\int\int x f'_x(x,y)\,dx\,dy=-1.  
\end{equation}
Here, $\int:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.
Also, $\int f'_x(x,y)\,dx=0$ and hence 
\begin{equation}
 Eh(Y)g(X,Y)=\int dy\,h(y)\int f'_x(x,y)\,dx=0
\end{equation}
for any function $h$ (satisfying appropriate regularity conditions). 
Therefore, $E(X-h(Y))g(X,Y)=-1$. 
Thus, by the Cauchy-- Schwarz inequality (hardly possible to do without it), 
\begin{equation}
 E(X-h(Y))^2\ge\frac1{Eg(X,Y)^2}. 
\end{equation}
Of course, here one can take $h(Y)=E(X|Y)$ (which actually minimizes the left-hand side of the last inequality).